# How to automate a ubuntu server ISO instalation so I can plug in, turn on, and ssh in?

Tags: drivers, system-installation, iso, custom-installer, wireless-keyboards

I'm having trouble installing Ubuntu server sue to the lack of proper  peripherals, the only keyboard I own is wireless USB and stops working at the "Select a language" prompt due to lack of a driver?

I want to ether figure out how to add the needed drivers to the ISO so I can use the keyboard to install, or customize the image to automate the installation and networking processes and install/start a sshd.

Here's the specs for my [PC](https://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/optix/en/opti_745techspecs.pdf/)
and [Keyboard](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/wireless-touch-keyboard-k400r/).

Thanks,
Benji

Answer (score 0):

two options:

1. get a wired keyboard: this is by far the easiest solution
2. Script the installation with a kickstart file.

Option 2 is complicated. Here is a guide:
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/ch04s06.html

I once had to do it on a server that had no GUI and minimal console. It sucks. Get the keyboard.